Setting up GitLab on Docker for Windows with Volumes Shared From a Linux Server
I have a GitLab instance in a Docker container running on a Synology NAS. Now, I want to move the GitLab to a Windows PC that I have, but keep the data on the NAS, by sharing folders and making them Docker volumes.
To test it, I created some folders config, data, and logs on the NAS and shared them on the network with "Shared Folder". From what I understand, we have it configured to use SMB for this. Then, on the Windows machine, I run (based on this suggestion)
docker volume create --driver local
  --opt type=cifs
  --opt device=//192.168.1.150/gitlab_docker_volume/config
  --opt o=user=gitlab_docker_volume,password=<password> gitlab-config

and two more to create gitlab-data and gitlab-logs.
Then, I start the container with
docker run -d -p 8070:80 -p 8433:443 -p 8012:22
  -v gitlab-logs:/var/log/gitlab:rw
  -v gitlab-data:/var/opt/gitlab:rw
  -v gitlab-config:/etc/gitlab:rw gitlab/gitlab-ce

and it crashes with the error
...
Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed:
Failed asserting that ownership of "/var/opt/gitlab/git-data" was git:git
...

2024-12-13 13:54:47 + [ root:root = git:git ]

When I look into the folders on the NAS, I can see that the container successfully created all of the files and folders GitLab needs, but they all have owner gitlab_docker_volume:users and 777 permissions.
In the data volume from the original GitLab container that is running on the NAS, the git-data folder belongs to some mysterious user 998 and it has 2770 permissions.
If I understand correctly, what's happening is that the GitLab container tries to chown the git-data folder and this command would have to be mapped across the SMB/CIFS share, but that isn't happening.
There are two posts about the same error, but they ran into it using different setups for their volumes - one of them seems to get the problem due to running the Windows server in a VM, the other one is using Windows-native folders.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134978/setting-up-gitlab-using-docker-on-windows-host-issue-with-shared-folders
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44684621/volume-trouble-with-gitlab-docker-image-on-windows
I've also tried to find out how to edit the Linux permissions through the network share in general, but the search results are flooded with "how to set the permissions when creating the folders so that the Docker container can edit them in the first place" - which was already working in my setup.
I, on the other hand, have shared folders that are originally on a Linux machine. Is there some way I can change the folder share setup, the volume setup, or anything else, so that the container can change the user and permissions of the files?
Docker is running with the WSL backend, by the way.

You have a number of problems. First, docker on windows isn't docker on windows; it's docker in a Linux VM. Second, docker uid's need not map to actual uses on host system. Third, Linux filesystem ACLs don't care about username, but UID:GID. You have to configure the permissions so that the effective Samba user has appropriate permissions to the files. In short, my suggestion would be not to do this; it sounds like an recipe for problems and bad performance.

I managed to get it working by sharing the folders using NFS instead of SMB.
Used these instructions. In short, the docker volume command is now
docker volume create --driver local
  --opt type=nfs
  --opt device=:/volume1/gitlab_docker_volume/config
  --opt o=addr=192.168.1.150,rw gitlab-config

Enabling NFS on the NAS is pretty obvious through the GUI. I don't have time to investigate getting the Kerberos security working, I imagine it's fiddly but possible. For now, this is enough for my purposes.
